# Fixing bootstrap navbar overflow

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I will be populating navbar dynamically and the number of items will different time to time.

When the items exceed the base container's width, the navbar splits into two lines. When this happens I want the navbar to be rendered something like the image I added below.

[image: Firefox]
[image: Chrome]

It is a screen shot of Firefox's title bar, where the arrows are placed at far left and far right but I want them to be displayed together at the right end of the navbar.

I searched for similar implementation elsewhere but was not able to find one.

**Code snippet:**

```css
.nav-tabs > li > a {
  background: #dbeef9;
  border: 1px solid #add2e6;
}
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<ul class="nav nav-tabs DefaultTab" id="main-tabs" role="tablist">
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab" id="li-menu-1">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item1
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item2
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item3
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="active">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item4
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item5
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item6
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item7
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item8
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item9
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item10
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item11
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item12
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item12
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item12
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item12
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item12
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="">
    <a href="#" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">
      <span class="pull-left tick"></span>Item12
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

`

Comment: Post some code please.

Comment: @gwar9 Updated my question

Comment: Could you try to draw exactly what are you trying to do? I couldn't figure it out what you want with this image from firefox.

Comment: @AndréSousa I added a new screen shot modifying chrome tabs and modified them. say the tabs are exceeding the given container space and its hidden in right side I will use the direction buttons to view all the tabs and select

Comment: @RandomUser Have you tried using an slider like Owl Carousel but instead of images, using buttons? It will achieve what you want.

Comment: @AndréSousa problem is I can not add any other plugins. Need to do it with bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

My way is using scroll but I think you can start with this [examples](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8f1hbymh/)

If you want use mouse to drag that scroll you can search about `dragscroll`like [this](https://fiddle.jshell.net/8f1hbymh/1/)